# Issues with async blocking GUI thread, WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asynchronous

I am having a strange issue with code that *should* work (to my best understanding), but it doesn't.

I have a windows forms application. It has a button that scans through a selected directory, which can result in a very high amount of files found. When scanning ~50k files, it took about 10 seconds.

I tried to implement async, to run the file scanning itself asynchronously to the main GUI, however this is causing trouble. The task itself runs fine, but it still blocks the GUI, resulting in freezing the whole application.

This is the code I have for the button

```
private async void BeginScanButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_osuDirectory == null)
            MessageBox.Show("You have not chosen an Osu! directory yet.");
        else
        {
            await ScanFilesTask();
        }
```

There is a lot more but this is the relevant part of it.

The task itself is

```
 private Task ScanFilesTask()
    {
        FileList.Clear();
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                if (_jpgFilesChecked)
                    FileParser.ParseFiles(_osuDirectory, "*.jpg");
                if (_pngFilesChecked)
                    FileParser.ParseFiles(_osuDirectory, "*.png");
                if (_wavFilesChecked)
                    FileParser.ParseFiles(_osuDirectory, "*.wav");
                if (_aviFilesChecked)
                    FileParser.ParseFiles(_osuDirectory, ".avi");
            });
    }
```

And finally, the FileParser class is just

```
        public static void ParseFiles(string dir, string extension)
        {
            Form1.FileList.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(dir, extension, SearchOption.AllDirectories));
        }
```

(All of the code is up on a [github repo](https://github.com/zirriously/OsuDeleter) if anyone wants to have a look. The relevant async code is in the AsyncTest branch.)

Any help here would be very much appreciated. This is my first real C# project, and would very much appreciate any pointers in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm surprised this even works.  You're executing `Form1.FileList.AddRange` from a `Task.Run()` which is on a different thread.  So I'd assume you're thread deadlocking your own application.  What is FileList?

Comment: FileList is a static list<string>.
It's static so I can add to it from FileParser.cs (I realise this is probably a completely idiotic way of doing it, but I wouldn't know how to go about changing it.)

Comment: In this case, because you are `await` (literally waiting) for `ScanFilesTask()` to complete, it's blocking the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you! It is working now - I moved the fileparsing logic inside the task, and it runs as expected. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Not quite!  I'm answering your question, with the best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to read:

[Task.Run Etiquette and Proper Usage](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html)

[Task.Run vs BackgroundWorker, Round 1: The Basic Pattern](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-round-1.html)

[A Tour of Task, Part 0: Overview](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/04/a-tour-of-task-part-0-overview.html)

Excerpt:

> - Developers who have used Task and the TPL (Task Parallel Library) since it was introduced in .NET 4.0. These developers are familiar with Task and how it is used in parallel processing. The danger that these developers face is that Task (as it is used by the TPL) is pretty much completely different than Task (as it is used by async).
> - Developers who have never heard of Task until async came along. To them, Task is just a part of async - one more (fairly complicated) thing to learn. “Continuation” is a foreign word. The danger that these developers face is assuming that every member of Task is applicable to async programming, which is most certainly not the case.

There is no point in Async, what you want is to run things in Parallel.  They are extremely different.  What you're looking for is:

button:

```
private void BeginScanButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BeginScanButton.Enabled = false;
    if (_osuDirectory == null)
        MessageBox.Show("You have not chosen an Osu! directory yet.");
        BeginScanButton.Enabled = false;
    else
    {
        ScanFilesInParallel();
    }
}
```

ScanFiles

```
private void ScanFilesInParallel()
{
    FileList.Clear();
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
      var result = new List<string>();

      if (_jpgFilesChecked)
        result.AddRange(FileParser.ParseFiles(_osuDirectory, "*.jpg"));
      if (_pngFilesChecked)
        result.AddRange(FileParser.ParseFiles(_osuDirectory, "*.png"));
      if (_wavFilesChecked)
        result.AddRange(FileParser.ParseFiles(_osuDirectory, "*.wav"));
      if (_aviFilesChecked)
        result.AddRange(FileParser.ParseFiles(_osuDirectory, ".avi"));

      return result;
     })
     .ContinueWith((task) => {
       FileList.AddRange(task.Result);
       BeginScanButton.Enabled = true;
     }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

ParseFiles

```
public IEnumerable<string> ParseFiles(string dir, string extension)
{
  var result = Directory.GetFiles(dir, extension, SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

  return result;
}
```

Comment: I would note that I should update this to avoid accessing the `_osu*` variables from inside the `Task.Run()`.

Comment: Hi - Thank you a lot for the help. However, I ran into a problem.

Trying to do this

`.ContinueWith<IEnumerable<string>>((files) => {FileList.AddRange(files);BeginScanButton.Enabled = true;},TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());`

.

gives the error `'Cannot resolve method ContinueWith(lambda expression System.Threading.Tasks.Taskscheduler)',`
 
I had a look myself, and I couldn't decode this error. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Updated.  I haven't used ContinueWith for a while, which passes the completed task into the Lamba.

Comment: It seems I may be missing something. I am getting the same error,
[this one](https://i.imgur.com/Fkkvrlq.png).

Comment: Can you copy just the `.ContinueWith()` to pastebin?

Comment: Actually - it seems like the error might be in the `=>` part, as attempting to build it only gives me the error `Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type 'Func<Task<List<string>>, IEnumerable<string>>'`

Comment: Oh my, I didn't need the generic `ContinueWith()`  try now (updated answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you an alternative that I think reads a little better; try using Microsoft's Reactive Framework.

Then you can do this:

```
private async void BeginScanButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_osuDirectory == null)
        MessageBox.Show("You have not chosen an Osu! directory yet.");
    else
    {
        var exts = new[]
        {
            _jpgFilesChecked ? "*.jpg" : null,
            _pngFilesChecked ? "*.png" : null,
            _wavFilesChecked ? "*.wav" : null,
            _aviFilesChecked ? "*.avi" : null,
        }.Where(x => x != null);

        var query =
            from ext in exts.ToObservable()
            from fs in Observable.Start(() => FileParser.ParseFiles(_osuDirectory, ext))
            from f in fs
            select f;

        var files = await query.ToArray();

        FileList.AddRange(files);
    }
}

public static class FileParser
{
    public static string[] ParseFiles(string dir, string extension)
    {
        return Directory.GetFiles(dir, extension, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    }
}
```

It's all processed in parallel and it completes on the UI thread.

NuGet "System.Reactive", "System.Reactive.Windows.Forms" and/or "System.Reactive.Windows.Threading" (WPF) to get the bits.